# delphi non-visual event handling in a dll

Tags: delphi, events, activex, ocx

I have a 3rd party Active X .ocx file that I have imported into Delphi XE2 and created a TLB file for.

The Active X library is a 'non-visual' component but shows as a image if dropped onto a form.

I want to call this component in an Active X library and can access its methods and properties fine, but do not know how to access its events.
I thought I could perhaps add it to a Data Module but this doesn't seem to be available as an option in the Tool Palette. Should this be possible?

I tried adding the events by doing something like this:
actX3Party := T3Party.Create(nil);
actX3Party.On3PartyEvent := myEventHandler;

but don't know how to make 'myEventHandler' an Event Handler as there is no form.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a form to implement an event handler. All you need is a class. You can implement an event handler using either instance methods or class methods. Naturally, if you choose to use instance methods, then you need to instantiate an instance.

So, decide whether you want to use instance methods or class methods. Then create a class that defines your event handlers. If you are using instance methods, instantiate the class. Finally, assign your handlers to the events.

For example:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  public
    class procedure MyHandler1(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MyHandler2(Sender: TObject);
  end;
```

I don't know what parameters you event receives, so the above is just for example's sake. And obviously you'll need to implement the methods.

You can use the class procedure immediately:

```
actX3Party.On3PartyEvent := TMyClass.MyHandler1;
```

For the instance method, make an instance:

```
myInstance := TMyClass.Create;
actX3Party.On3PartyEvent := myInstance.MyHandler2;
```

If the code which is assigning the event handlers to the ActiveX control exists in a class, then you don't need another class. You can implement your handlers right there in that class.

So, one more time, event handlers do not need to be implemented in a form. They are simply methods of a class.

Comment: Technically, it is possible to implement an event handler without using a class at all. You can use the `TMethod` record and a typecast to accomplish the same thing. The only requirement is that you have to add an additional explicit parameter to the event handler to accommodate the `Self` value, but the `TMethod` allows you to specify whatever value you want for the `Self` parameter. It does not need to be an object pointer or class reference.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Technically that is indeed true. I did not think that sort of level of detail was appropriate here.

Comment: since the OP was asking how to create event handlers without a Form, I thought it was worth mentioning that a class-less approach exists.

Comment: @Remy Would you do it that way? Or would you do it the way that allows the compiler to ensure type safety?

Comment: I have done it both ways. It depends on the situation. But using a Form/DataModule to create event handlers does not guarantee type safety since a DFM throws away all type information for event handlers. Changes in event signatures between versions are not reflected in DFMs, and can cause errors that only appear at runtime. Also, using a Form/DataModule to hook up event handlers visually rather than programmably does not allow for compiler validations of any kind, since the compiler is not invoked. The IDE does the validations, based on RTTI, and it has been known to be wrong sometimes.

Comment: @Remy Experience suggests that such problems are rare. And in any case the question at hand involves compiler checked assignments rather than .dfm RTTI assignments.